# Data is not being displayed in the RecyclerView using SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I am using SQLite Database to store & display data to the RecyclerView. I am able to Store the Data to the Database however the data is not being displayed to the RecyclerView.I need to close and restart the application then only the data is displayed in the RecyclerView.

The following screenshot displays Add_Data Activity, as I enter the values for Name,Age and Country

[Add_Data Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAlCX.png)

The following screenshot is for the RecyclerView, I need to restart the app then only the user details appear in the RecyclerView

[RecyclerView Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gXtp.png)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyAdapter madapter;
ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Add_Data.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.id_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    madapter = new MyAdapter(this,models);

    retrieveData();

}

public void retrieveData()
{
    Cursor c = myDB.getAllUserData();
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        int id = c.getInt(0);
        String name = c.getString(1);
        String age = c.getString(2);
        String country = c.getString(3);

        Model m = new Model(id,name,age,country);
        models.add(m);
    }

    if (!(models.size()<1))
    {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "profile.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "profile_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "AGE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "COUNTRY";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, AGE TEXT, COUNTRY TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String name, String age, String country) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3, age);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, country);
        long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (res == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllUserData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.COL_1, DatabaseHelper.COL_2,
                DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
        return db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
Context c;
ArrayList<Model> models;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
    this.c = c;
    this.models = models;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.userName.setText(models.get(position).getName());
    holder.userAge.setText(models.get(position).getAge());
    holder.userCountry.setText(models.get(position).getCountry());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView userName,userAge,userCountry;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameHere);
        userAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAgeHere);
        userCountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCountryHere);
    }
}
}
```

Model.java (POJO class)

```
public class Model
{
private int id;
private String name,age,country;

public Model(int id, String name, String age, String country)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.country = country;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
}
```

Add_Data.java

```
public class Add_Data extends AppCompatActivity
{
EditText name,age,country;
Button save_user;
DatabaseHelper myDB;


@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__data);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etage);
    country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcountry);
    save_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_user);
   myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    save_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            boolean isInserted = myDB.addData(name.getText().toString(),
                    age.getText().toString(),
                    country.getText().toString());

            if (isInserted = true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Add_Data.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Add_Data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            finish();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the

```
retrieveData();
```

to the `onResume()` method.

Also, not related but, this line is wrong:

```
if (isInserted = true)
```

should be

`if (isInserted == true)` or `if (isInserted)`

**EDIT:**

Also,

Make the first instruction of `retrieveData()` function `models.clear();`

Comment: Thanks! Now it’s working but as i enter the details for the second user the first user’s details are printed twice in the recyclerview

Comment: The first thing you should do on the retrieveData() function is models.clear();

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!(models.size()<1))
{
    recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
}
```

You should set your adapter even if the list is still empty.

In your adapter, make a refresh function like this

```
    public void refresh(List<Model> models) {       
this.models = models;
 this.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Then call madapter.refresh() when your data are retrieved;